# Is it possible to have in Robotframework, hooks after execution like Ruby/Cucumber

Tags: python, cucumber, hook, robotframework, robotframework-ide

Ruby and Cucumber have a hooks file(hooks.rb) that allow to execute actions **before and/or after features, scenarios, steps or even** in program **at_exit**.

This allow to do some important operations(like scripts) that I do not want to include them in test execution report.

In Robotframework I only know **Suite/Test Setup/Teardown**.

This prints actions in logs and I have to implement/call this for all test suites(distinct files) and it can't be done globally, for all tests, only once.

Is there a way to do this, somehow? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you search for is probably listener interface: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface

Comment: Listeners works perfect but is it possible to add a kind off hook/listener method that executes code like "at_exit". After a KW, a TC, a TS, in program exiting?

Comment: Yes. There are `end_test`, `end_suite` and `close` methods in listener v3 interface and moreover `end_keyword` in listener v2. Please see the doc (as linked above in answer). Is it what are you looking for?